# What's the best way to handle authentication across multiple different domains under the same service?

Tags: authentication, php, web-browser, cookies, iframe

For a social networking site `example.com`, users all have their own domains. How can you keep someone seamlessly authenticated across all domains?

For the main site, `example.com`, I am currently using:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //handle session data
?>
```

This creates the `PHPSESSID` cookie for the user. They remain logged in to their account on `example.com`.

However, for all the different domains belonging to different users, they get a different `PHPSESSID` cookie when visiting:

- `user5454.example.com`
- `customdomain.com`
- `user85923.example.com`

Even though the domains are different, the same user must be authenticated to the same account regardless of the domain.

What I am currently doing is putting an `<iframe>` that points to `example.com` for each of the different domains and user actions occur through that.

Is that the correct way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you doing this through sessions and not authentication tokens? Why does the session need to be the same? Do they have different logins, or do you want them to have a single authentication across the multiple domains?

Comment: @schroeder Do you have an example of how I can do that? Or any references I can look at?

Comment: Have you looked up OWASP guidance? https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @schroeder Is it OK to do it through Iframes? That's currently working - when a user needs to do an authenticated action on `customdomain.com`, it happens through an iframe that points to `example.com` where they are already logged in